# Getting NettyTcpClient connection error with Spring WebSocket with amqp broker (rabbitmq) while running in docker

Tags: spring, docker, spring-websocket

I am trying to use the rabbitmq as the StompBroker in the WebSocketConfig. Have added the dependencies `reactor-core` and `reactor-net`

It works fine when starting up locally (localhost) but when I try to start the project as a docker container (rabbitmq image is correctly built with STOMP plugin), I get below error.

`r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:61613. Attempting reconnect in 5000ms`

I tried setting the `setRelayHost("rabbitmq")` and `setRelayPort(61613)` (since rabbitmq is the service name in the docker compose, using it to resolve the host name). No luck still.

Comment: The `reactor-core` and `reactor-net` version 2.0.8.RELEASE fixed this. I previously was using 2.0.7.RELEASE as a managed version with spring boot.